# How do I unitize a variable in structure that is of type structure

Tags: json, swift, structure

I have been working with reading JSON files.  With help I have been able to do so but now want to expand what I read from the JSON file.  I think I have the structures set up correctly but do not understand how to initialize the metaData variable in the Stock structure when I create an instance of the structure from the ReadData class.  I have placed ?'s in the line of code in the ReadData that is giving me problems
Any help would be appreciated.
Chris
Below is the JSON data and my code.

```
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "VOO",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-09-22",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-09-22": {
        "1. open": "402.1700",
        "2. high": "405.8500",
        "3. low": "401.2600",
        "4. close": "403.9000",
        "5. volume": "5979811"
    },

struct Stock: Codable {
    let metaData: MetaData
    let timeSeriesDaily: [String : TimeSeriesDaily]  // creates a dictionary, key = string : TimeSeriesDaily = value
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
}
struct MetaData: Codable {
    let Information : String
    let Symbol : String
    let LastRefreshed : String
    let OutputSize : String
    let TimeZone: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Information = "1. Information"
        case Symbol = "2. Symbol"
        case LastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
        case OutputSize = "4. Output Size"
        case TimeZone = "5. Time Zone"
    }
}
struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    let Open, High, Low, Close: String
    let Volume: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Open = "1. open"
        case High = "2. high"
        case Low = "3. low"
        case Close = "4. close"
        case Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}
class ReadData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var tmpData = Stock(metaData: ????? , timeSeriesDaily : [:])
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "VOO", withExtension: "json")
        else {
            print("Json file not found")
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.tmpData = try decoder.decode(Stock.self, from: data)
//            print(self.tmpData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vooData = ReadData()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView  {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                let lastYear = getOneYearAgo()
                let filteredDict = vooData.tmpData.timeSeriesDaily.filter { $0.key > lastYear } // Works
//                let sortedFilteredDict = filteredDict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }                 // Works
//                let justCloseArray = sortedFilteredDict.map { ($0.key, $0.value.Close) }           // returns array [(String, String)]
//                let justCloseDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: justCloseArray)                // returns dictionary with 1 key & 1 val
//                let sortedCloseDict = justCloseDict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }                      // works
                let newDict = filteredDict.mapValues { Double($0.Close) }
                let sortedNewDict = newDict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
                Spacer()
                //                ForEach ( sortedCloseDict.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }, id: \.0 ) { keyValuePair in
                ForEach ( sortedNewDict.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }, id: \.0 ) { keyValuePair in   // map converts dictionary to arrap
                    HStack {
                        Text (keyValuePair.0)
                        Text ("\(keyValuePair.1!)")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            } // end vstack
        } .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .center) // end scroll view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `MetaData` struct to it. The initializer for `MetaData` takes a number of `Strings` that match its properties:

```
@Published var tmpData = Stock(metaData: MetaData(Information: "", Symbol: "", LastRefreshed: "", OutputSize: "", TimeZone: ""), timeSeriesDaily: [:])
```

---

One hint is that Xcode will autocomplete a lot of this for you. If you start typing `Stock` and let autocomplete do the work, you'll see it generate templates for the `metaData` and `timeSeriesDaily` parameters.

Comment: Thank you.  One try was metaData: MetaData() but I forgot all about initializing the variable

Comment: Glad it worked. If the answer was helpful to you, please consider using the arrow to upvote it.